# ¿Cómo resolver este problema en R: Argument is not numeric or logical?

Tags: r, rstudio, programación-funcional, calculo

Lo que pasa es que me sale este error en esta linea cuando trato de calcular una media muestral:

> **Warninng Message In mean default(Muestreado1$Incremento): argument is**
>   **not numeric or logical.**

Código:

```
ruta<-file.choose()
data<-read.table(ruta, header = TRUE)
data
N=nrow(data)
muestra1<-sample(1:N,16)
Muestreado1<-data[muestra1,]
attach(Muestreado1)
Muestreado1


incremento<-as.numeric(Muestreado1$Incremento)
mean(Muestreado1$Incremento)
```

Lo he estado intentado resolver con el comando `as numeric` pero aun así persiste el error :(

Comment: En principio tienes un error de diseño, no estas calculando la media sobre el valor convertido sino sobre el original, prueba con `mean(incremento)`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar dos cosas, una revisar que en tu archivo no haya comas ',' ya que esto se toma como string tambien revisa que no haya mas de 1 punto decimal, de igual manera si no hay puedes usar la funcion `round()`